# Underlapping a div

Tags: image, html

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/KBcwe/9/). I am making a vote up button for my site, and I have an arrow-shaped character pointing to the button. I have an image in the div, and after I put the image in, the text and image inside the div were pushed down. I want the text and image to be inside the div.

HTML:

```
<button id="b">
  0
</button><div id='votes'>&leftarrow; Votes <img id='votel' src='http://i.imgur.com/lVbnNwy.png?1' /></div>
```

Comment: This looks like a case where a background image would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `margin-top`:

```
#votel {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;

}
```